# makefile compiles only the first source file

Tags: gcc, makefile, compilation, object-files

I have a list of two source files, but the makefile compiles the first source file twice.
This is my makefile:

```
Source = ../Src
Source_Files = $(Source)/File_1.c  \
               $(Source)/File_2.c 

Obj = ./Obj
Object_Files = $(notdir $(Source_Files))
Object_Files := $(Object_Files:.c=.o)
Object_Files := $(addprefix $(Obj)/, $(Object_Files))

all: $(Object_Files)

$(Object_Files): $(Source_Files) 
    @echo Compile $<
    @gcc -o $@ -c $<
```

The output looks like this:
Compile ../Src/File_1.c
Compile ../Src/File_1.c

Why File_2.c does not get compiled?

Answer (score 1):

`$<` means "the first dependency", and since `$(Source_Files)` is always `$(Source)/File_1.c  $(Source)/File_2.c`, the first dependency is always `$(Source)/File_1.c`.

To get what you want, you need to use [patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#Pattern-Intro), e.g.

```
$(Object_Files): $(Obj)/%.o: $(Source)/%.c
    @echo Compile $<
    @gcc -o $@ -c $<
```

With this code, there is only one dependency, and it is the one generated from the current target.